# MongoDB update value and save others

Tags: mongodb, document

Here is a sample data:

```
{
  x : 3,
  firstName: "James",
  lastName: "Bond"
}
```

Now I want to update firstName from "James" to "Peter" without chaing x and lastName. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator, for example:

```
db.collection.update({x: 3}, {$set: {firstName: 'Peter'}});
```

I added `{x: 3}` as the first parameter because you need to find this document somehow. If the document has an `_id` field, you can use it this way:

```
db.collection.update({_id: ObjectId("507c35dd8fada716c89d0013")}, {$set: {firstName: 'Peter'}});
```

Comment: db.collection.update({"firstName":"James"},{$set:{"firstName":"Peter"}}) would also work.

Comment: @JohnBarça True, but usually first names are not unique in a collection. I added two examples, I can't provide a better query without more information.